# TesseractNotFoundError: C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract (2).exe is not installed or it's not in your PATH. See README file for more info

Tags: python, windows, google-colaboratory, tesseract

I wrote the following code for extracting text form image in google colab:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesseract import pytesseract

path_to_tesseract = r"C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract (2).exe"
image_path = r"/content/images/result_Page_1.jpg"

img = Image.open(image_path)

pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = path_to_tesseract

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

print(text[:-1])
```

I am still getting tesseract not found error. I am using google colab on windows 10 laptop.

Comment: your path_to_tesseract is pointing to a local resource on your machine. It should point to colab's virtual machine instead

Comment: what now, Windows or Colab? it's not both. Google doesn't offer Windows servers. -- welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre].